# Exploding an array of strings

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, explode

I have an array from a post operation

```
$country = $_POST['country']; //The number of countries differ according to the user selection
$c = count($country);
```

Output: `

```
Array ( [0] => England,69,93 [1] => Australia,79,84 [2] => Greece,89,73 [3] => Germany,59,73 )`
```

I will have to break it into a multidimensional array like:

```
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => England [1] => 69 [2] => 93)
>         [1] => Array ( [0] => Australia [1] => 79 [2] => 84)                      
>         [2] => Array ( [0] => Greece [1] => 89 [2] => 73)
>         [3] => Array ( [0] => Germany [1] => 59 [2] => 73))
```

How do I do this in PHP

I tried

```
$r = array();

foreach($country as &$r){
  $r = explode(",", $r);
  //for($i = 0; $i < count($country); $i++){
    //for($j = 0; $j < count($r); $j++){
        //$array[$i][$j] = $r;
    //}
  //}
}
echo '<br>';
print_r($r);
```

The for-loop also did not work and hence commented it out but left it as a an option if needed.

The print function now only prints 1 of the array. Not exactly sure what have I done wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: try `print_r($country);` after your loop instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there:

```
$r = array();

foreach($country as $country_item){
  $r[] = explode(",", $country_item);
}
echo '<br>';
print_r($r);
```

The above should work.

What might be even better for you (if your country is unique in each array):

```
$r = array();

foreach($country as $country_item){
  $temp_array = explode(",", $country_item);
  $r[$temp_array[0]] = array($temp_array[1], $temp_array[2]); 
}
echo '<br>';
print_r($r);
```

This will give you an output like follows:

```
> Array ( [England] => Array ( [0] => 69 [1] => 93)
>         [Australia] => Array ( [0] => 79 [1] => 84)                      
>         [Greece] => Array ( [0] => 89 [1] => 73)
>         [Germany] => Array ( [0] => 59 [1] => 73))
```

This therefore means you can access a countries figures as follows:

```
$r[$country_name];
```

Comment: Thank you so much...I still don't understand though... As I did use this line... $r[] = explode(",", $country_item); and for that I get an error: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\wamp\www\clar\test5.php on line 21... yet it worked when I typed your code... Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($country);$i++)
 {
      $country1[$i] = explode(",", $country[$i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your $r main array with the $r from the loop - this is the solution - always divide your vars:

```
$output = array();
foreach($country as $c){
  $parts = explode(',',$c);
  $output[] = $parts; 
}

print_r($output);
```